# MySQL INTERVAL Mins

Tags: mysql, intervals

I am trying to get the all records which are 2 hours or more old using this query:

```
$minutes = 60 * 2

SELECT COUNT(id) AS TOTAL, job_id 
  from tlb_stats 
 WHERE log_time >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL $minutes MINUTE) 
GROUP BY job_id
```

It only selects the recent records and skips the old. When I change `log_time <= ...` it only selects old and skips which are the new one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing all right - that is what this query should do.

Comment: why it isn't selecting the old records?

Comment: @jason4: because you want the records with a time _less or equal_ (`<=`) to the current time minus 2 minutes, (i.e. now: 22:06, 2 mins ago is 22:04, so you want a record with 22:03, which is less then 22:04).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try:

```
$minutes = 60 * 2

SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `TOTAL`, `job_id` 
  FROM `tlb_stats` 
  WHERE `log_time` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $minutes MINUTE) 
  GROUP BY `job_id`
```

- use backticks to quote fields (words like "total" and "id" may someday *mean* something in MySQL)
- use `NOW()` for CURRENT_DATE just means 2010-08-04, not including the time
- use `<` to get entries *older* than that date.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE CURTIME() >= (`colname` + INTERVAL 120 MINUTE)
```

Here, `colname` is the column where you added timestamp at the time when the record was created.

Comment: Recommend rearranging the expression to `WHERE colname <= ...` so that `INDEX(... colname)` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in this way:

```
$minutes = 60 * 2

SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `TOTAL`,
       `job_id` 
FROM `tlb_stats` 
WHERE `log_time` < NOW() - INTERVAL $minutes MINUTE
GROUP BY `job_id`
```