# Search record between 3 date ranges

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, time

I need to output data from a DB table that selects records between 3 (not 2) date/time ranges

E.g. start time : 2019-09-07 18.00 
      end time : 2019-09-07 20.00

so the user should be able to see the record 25 minutes before the start date-time (6.p.m - 18.00), during the event but not after the end date-time (8.p.m -20.00).

I've tried

```
db->query = "SELECT o_id, schedule, date, start_time, end_time FROM working_schedule WHERE o_id = '".$user_id."'
AND (start_time <= '".date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime("-25 minutes"))."' AND start_time >= '".date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s')."') 
AND end_time >= '".date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s')."'";
```

but the result is NULL.

For reference [HERE'S](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa57ce/3) a sql fiddle.

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Simplify the issue, is it PHP related? You can do the date/math differential in mysql. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401551/mysql-interval-mins

Comment: What does your query's value(s) show as opposed to what is in your database?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner current output is NULL if this is what you want to know, otherwise i didn't get your question.

Comment: @Someone33 what I meant was, if you "echo" the query out and/or `var_dump()` it, what does it show exactly? Seeing that, it might help you to figure out what isn't working the way you want it to. Another thing; if you're storing dates as plain text, MySQL has built-in features made just for this, which makes querying a lot easier.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Oh ok, so i was correct; If i do a "var_dump($this->db->get_row($query));" , the result is NULL, so the result is nothing. That's what confuses me.

Comment: Your code is probably vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: Sounds like something failed. Enable error reporting for both the PHP and MySQL.

Comment: @Dharman Thanks, all data is escaped correctly, i just simplified the code here. Btw, my question wasn't about sql vulnerability.

Comment: That is the problem. You should not escape anything. Use prepared statements.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I've made a quick sql fiddle, there are 0 returned records, so result is NULL : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa57ce/3

Comment: Try to randomly change `<=` and `>=` until you get the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need this ?

```
 select * from working_schedule
 where
 NOW() BETWEEN DATE_SUB(start_time,INTERVAL 25 MINUTE)  AND end_time
```

Comment: Great, that's it! Many Thanks, would never have tought like this.